reposync fails until clearing folder and redownloading all
I do the following:
reposync --download-metadata --norepopath --download_path=/repo7/RPMFusion                             --repoid=rpmfusion-free-updates
reposync --download-metadata --norepopath --download_path=/repo7/epel                                  --repoid=epel
reposync --download-metadata --norepopath --download_path=/repo7/rhel-7-server-supplementary-rpms      --repoid=rhel-7-server-supplementary-rpms
reposync --download-metadata --norepopath --download_path=/repo7/rhel-7-server-extras-rpms             --repoid=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
reposync --download-metadata --norepopath --download_path=/repo7/rhel-7-server-optional-rpms           --repoid=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
reposync --download-metadata --norepopath --download_path=/repo7/rhel-7-server-rpms                    --repoid=rhel-7-server-rpms

This has been successful.  When doing subsequent reposync it only downloads the new stuff.  Currently when trying to reposync any of them the command hangs for a few seconds then the prompt returns without any downloading happening.
Not until I cleared everything out under my /repo7/* did the reposync start working, but now I have to wait all day to redownload 100+ gb.
Is there a way to correct this error when reposync fails  other than clearing everything so I don't have to re-download everything?  And also a way to diagnose what is failing when the reposync just doesn't do anything and the prompt returns?
